# Can you change the URL for Assets uploaded to a Rackspace CDN?

Tags: assets

Assuming that you're using Craft Pro, is it possible to change the URL from the long randomly generated character string to something more user friendly?

Currently: http://83af0ee9e3c8cba9844f-a33048c0ede2332addff32deec6d7158.r40.cf3.rackcdn.com/subFolder/randomImage.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really Craft related, but: for this to work in Craft, you should first make sure Rackspace recognizes the url you want to use. They explain how to do this [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-cnames-with-cloud-files-containers).

In short: create a CNAME record for your domain, pointing to your Rackspace domain. After doing that, change the display url for your asset source.